# Accidentally made my Netbeans Project folder a github repository

Tags: java, git, netbeans, github, repository

I've just finished a java course and a project in which we made a small java application. In the project we used github, but since we're all pretty much beginners to java and github this was a rather confusing process.

Therefore I might have made my NetBeansProjects folder, which is NetBeans' default folder for new projects, a repository to our project on github.

At least what happens is that every time I create a new project in NetBeans, it's automatically connected to our project on github.
I'd really like that my NetBeansProjects folder isn't connected to any remote github projects.

I have tried the `git remote remove origin` which resets the config by the looks of it but it doesn't solve the problem and any projects I create in NetBeans will still connect to our project on github.

Any suggestions to what might help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to keep track of anything in the Netbeans folder anymore, then you can just erase the `.git` folder which keeps all the git related data (you will lose everything that hasn't been pushed to github repo as well). The `.git` directory is hidden, procedure to make it visible (/display & erase it) depends on the OS you are using.

If you want to keep using git, you can add the folders you don't want to have in github repo into `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I couldn't figure out how to make the `.git` visible so instead I entered my NetBeansProjects folder in the command line and deleted the `.git` with `rm -Rf .git`.